# How to install specific version of BigBlueButton?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, bigbluebutton

I want to install BigBlueButton and found the following command from [BigBlueButton official website][1]

`wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v bionic-230-dev -s bbb.example.com -e notice@example.com  -a -w`

My question is how to install another version.
for example with this command i will install version `bionic-230-dev`, But i need to install version `2.3 alpha 2`.I couldn't find any list for the available versions to replace
[1]: https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/dev23.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not particularly sure for the alpha release, however I was looking for for a similar answer with the release branch. I was running the following provided by the [bigbluebutton/bbb-install](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install) documentation:

`wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -w -v xenial-22 -s bbb.example.com -e notice@example.com`

However, that always installs the latest BBB release.

After a bit of searching through the bbb dev google group, I found the following solution:

Update `-v xenial-22` to `-v xenial-220-2.2.27`, and I was able to install the particular version I was looking for, `2.2.27`.

I gave a small attempt to figure out the install tag for the alpha version, but I was unable to find anything for your use case in particular. If you did come across a solution, please share.

---

One thing to note, that because it is an alpha version, it is subject to breaking changes, which is why I haven't adapted to the 2.3 version until it is officially released. There's a chance that they just update the alpha release tag, without creating a new one, which could be why I couldn't find a particular tag for the version you were requesting. Ultimately, I believe you might need to reach out to the BBB dev google group, to determine the specific release tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the commit history of readme file ([here](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install/commits/master/README.md)). By this way, you can see the shell command to install older versions of bbb.

For example, you can install version 2.0 as follows ([see commit](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install/commit/5f155ca591a32756db098adce7ec9fdf6f123d39#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5)):

```
wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -w -a -v xenial-200 -s test.example.com -e info@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to install an exact specific release of bigbluebutton (alpha, beta, ...), you should find the release in [here(releases list)](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/releases) and at there, there is a paragraph titled **Release name** where you can find versioning and installation instructions.